# Access everywhere to an UIImageView added under UIWindow

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, subview, uiwindow

In my app start delegate I have the following code:

```
[window addSubview:[myTabBarController view]];

UIImageView *banner = 
     [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,381,320,50)] autorelease];
banner.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 

[window addSubview:banner];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This works as expected. The tab bar is visible and also my `UIImageView` is visible.

I need to modify that `UIImageView` everywhere in my app (I have the `TabBarController`, a `NavigationController`, `UITableView`, etc)

For example, I want to change the background color when I click in a `UITableCell`.

I tried everything: `self.window.view.subviews`, `atObjectIndex`, neither seems to get the current background color.

Answer (score 0):

first you do not need an UIImageView if its just to set a background-color. A UIView is sufficient.

to solve your problem, you can keep a reference to the view who's background-color you want to change in you AppDelegate. you can then access you AppDelegate (and the the reference to your view) from anywhere in your app like so:

```
((YouAppDelegateName*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).yourViewReferenceProperty
```

Comment: thanks, i added a property to my appdelegate, and modify it with your code

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do that?

It's usually best to arrange your app so that the only object manipulating a view controller's view hierarchy is that view controller. If other objects want to change something, they either change the data model or send a message to the view controller. So, you might give your view controller a 'backgroundColor' property, and its setter would update the appropriate view. Setting the background color indirectly through the view controller makes it easier to make changes to your view hierarchy in the future and generally keeps things better organized.